# Not show in map in MapView at iPhone Device

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview

In UIViewController, MKMapView attahced.

If I use one of network vender (SKTelecome in Korea), I can't see map.(just display grid) I tried zoom change, move to other position in map, but it's very frequently occurred.

Does anyone know a solution?

```
 Error downloading tiles Server Error: Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-204 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (GEOErrorDomain error -204.)" UserInfo=0x27a02f00 {UnderlyingErrors=(
"Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 \"Could not connect to the server.\" UserInfo=0x27a02fc0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost/2/tiles?sid=200858392884450040417818215884823473791&tk=52e0ab4bf70155655f3bc363c1f75553&mapkey=1378442549_2311f6b13b1ea64c10887d8b187da020, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost/2/tiles?sid=200858392884450040417818215884823473791&tk=52e0ab4bf70155655f3bc363c1f75553&mapkey=1378442549_2311f6b13b1ea64c10887d8b187da020, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSUnderlyingError=0x27a03f90 \"Could not connect to the server.\"}"
```

Comment: You say this happens on SKTelecome , does it work via wifi?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but your error seems to suggest that you are trying to access some local network URL (`http://localhost/2/tiles`). Specifically this part,

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 \"Could not connect to the server.\" UserInfo=0x27a02fc0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost/2/tiles?sid=200858392884450040417818215884823473791&tk=52e0ab4bf70155655f3bc363c1f75553&mapkey=1378442549_2311f6b13b1ea64c10887d8b187da020
```

If there is any webservice involved to fetch map tiles or any other infomation, make sure that server has a public IP which can be accessed from mobile data network.

Comment: That is just MKMapView's log. MKMapView request url for map loading. I think MKMapView request map to apple's map server. So I can't understand that URL-localhost. I tried to change DNS server to 8.8.8.8 (by google). But nothing changed.

Comment: @hjpark Is it accessing custom tile images?

Comment: No... Just MKMapView. Use on one custom annotation.